# Labview fluid flow

Tags: time, labview

This is a two part question:

I have a fluid flow sensor connected to an NI-9361 on my DAQ. For those that don't know, that's a pulse counter card. None the less, from the data read from the card, I'm able to calculate fluid flowing through the device in Gallons per hour, min, sec, etc. But what I need to do is the following:

- Calculate total number of gallons of fluid that has flowed through the sensor since the loop began running
- if possible, store that total so that it can be incremented next time the program runs

I know how to calculate it by hand, just not sure how to achieve the running summation required to calculate total amount of fluid that has passed through the sensor, or how to store the variable being incremented at the next program execution. I'm presuming the latter would involve writing a TDMS file, then opening and reading back the data, unless there's a better way?

Edit:

Below is the code used to determine GPM flow through my sensor. This setup is in accordance with the 9361 manual; it executes and yields proper results.

[image]

See this link for details:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373197L-01/criodevicehelp/crio-9361/

I can extrapolate how many gallons flow per second, or sample period, the 1526.99 scalar is the fluid flow manufacturer's constant - number of pulses per gallon passing through the sensor. The 9361 is set to frequency/period mode, so I'm calculating cycles per second, dividing by the constant for cycles per gallon to get gallons per second/min.

I suppose I could get a time reference by looking at the sample period, so I guess the better question is, how do I keep an incrementing sum?

Comment: This comment pertains to the second bullet: If you're only interested in storing a single value between sessions, I'd recommend writing to a simple text file. In fact, this would be an ideal use for a config file. Read from the file at the beginning of the loop & then write to the file after the loop has stopped.

Comment: _just not sure how to achieve the delta-t required to calculate total amount of fluid that has passed through the sensor_ :: My immediate thought is: `sample_rate * total_amount_of_samples`.

Comment: How often are you reading from the DAQ card and how exactly are you doing the reading - which DAQ functions and how are they configured?

Comment: @nekomatic - the GUI gets a packet from the DAQ at 500Hz. The DAQ card, a 9361, samples at 20kHz.

Comment: @JediEngineer It would be very helpful if you edit your question to include a description of how the digital pulses correlate to the flow. For example, does the sensor generate N pulses per gallon?

Comment: @JKSH - code snippet added.

Comment: @JediEngineer How frequently is that code run? Which Measurement Mode are you using? What does the 1526.99 represent? What's the array size for A and B?

Comment: @JKSH - updated